# Laravel 8 : Route with parameter in Routegroup don't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i've trouble with laravel localization and route in grouproute.

I try to access this url :
http://localhost/logiluxe/public/en/games_giveaways/1

My routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['setlocale'],'prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], function() {
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/games_giveaways/{id}', [GameGiveawayController::class, 'show'])->name('games_giveaways.show');
});
```

My middleware :

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
        if(session()->has('locale')){
            app()->setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
            //Carbon::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
        } elseif ($request->segment(1)) {
            app()->setLocale($request->segment(1)); 
        } else {
            app()->setLocale('en');  
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

The error :

```
    Missing required parameter for [Route: games_giveaways.show] [URI: {locale}/games_giveaways/{id}]
 [Missing parameter: id]. (View: C:\wamp64\www\logiluxe\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

It's look like i can't have a route with parameter in a routegroup.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the balde, not the route declaration itself.

Somewhere in your blade you are calling the route by alias without the ID parameter.

```
//change this in your blade
route('games_giveaways.show', ['locale' => 'en']);
//to
route('games_giveaways.show', ['locale' => 'en', 'id' => 1]);
```

Comment: I did this. I have exactly the same error as initial post.

Comment: @Shäninjah You still have it somewhere else. use tools like grepwin/grep to search for `games_giveaways.show` in your blades/codes

Comment: I've only one call to my route :

`route('games_giveaways.show', ['locale' => 'en', 'id' => 1]);`

I think the problem come from having one route with parameter (id) in a group route with parameter (locale). Even when i access my page with direct url writing in browser, i've this error

Comment: In error, i've locale and id defined. 

`Route parameters
locale : en
id : 1`